# crud operation and function with a an abstract class of which it had two subclasses

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, inheritance

I have 4 classes: the abstract Article class of which it had two subclasses TV, Phone and the Movement class (details mvt, supplier, article)
the question that arises is how I should organize my Crud functions with Article (either Tv or Phone) and map the Article class with Movement class.

I tried to do the Crud operation of the article class:
example:
add article (Artcilesevice)
serviceImplArticle -> to identify whether Tv or Phone using the “InstanceOf” function.
And display the list of Articles by the Name attribute of the Article class (Name = designationTv + codeTv or designationPhone + codePhone) but that doesn't work
I see that I need help to better organize and understand what I need to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.